# iOS App not showing Japanese Language Keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, uikeyboard, cjk

I have a small issue, the issue is the Keyboards that I am adding from settings -> General-> Keyboards -> Japanese are not getting visible in my iOS App. For example, I added Japanese Keyboard Kana and listed it on the top list, it is still not getting displayed in my App. However it is getting displayed in other Apps like Apple Notes and all.

Did anyone face the same issue. I really need solution for this.

Thanks [here is the screenshots of my keyboards added in keyboard section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4MBv.png)

Comment: So what *do* you get in your app, and what exactly does your app do?

Comment: What app are you using?

Comment: I always get normal english keyboard and my App is native iOS App. Basically a chat application

Answer (score 0):

Press the globe icon to switch between keyboard layouts. Its position will differ slightly depending on the layout.

[image: Globe icon]